# Understanding SQL Server kill statement [for non-admin user]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking into how a database management system performs a "cancel" operation when the cancel button is hit on the query. While it doesn't show what query it runs when it does cancel, here is what it shows in the logs:

```
2019/01/03 22:09:16:433  MSSQL cancelCurrentQuery failed via spid (54). Error: Msg 6102, Level 14, State 2.

User does not have permission to use the KILL statement.

2019/01/03 22:09:16:433  MSSQL cancelCurrentQuery is going to try via dbcancel.

2019/01/03 22:09:16:533  Cancelling current query (finished).
```

I assume `KILL` is trying to do `KILL {sid}` and it fails to do that because of permissions and then calls back to dbcancal. What is dbcancel? And what would be an example of that from the command line?

Additionally, how is it possible for me to kill the queries that I've issued if I cannot use the kill command?

> Msg 6102, Level 14, State 2.
>   User does not have permission to use the KILL statement. (Line 1)

Comment: I believe `dbcancel` is not a T-SQL command, but a function from the database access library used by SSMS.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov I see -- what do you think that command would be doing then? Is it possible to kill your own running query if you're not an admin user? For example, what if you issue a bad long-running query and need to kill/cancel it?

Comment: This function can kill (or we should better say cancel) your own query, executed asynchronously by your program, using the API. See for example the ADO [Cancel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cancel-method-ado?view=sql-server-2017) method. And I believe it is at least partially a client operation (like timeouts for example), so it is irrelevant what rights you have on the server. If it can't stop the query execution on the server, at least the client connection will be released.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov thanks for that -- can this be executed within the MsSQL shell? Or how exactly would I call that method?

Comment: No, you can't execute it like that. It is used when you write programs (e.g. in C++), and you started execution of a query with ADO [Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/command-object-ado?view=sql-server-2017) object. Then you can cancel the execution of this particular command by calling it's Cancel method.

Comment: What tool are you using to cancel the query? Cancelling a running query does not typically issue a `KILL` command (which forcibly terminates the session and connection). A cancel from client applications like sends an attention request on the same session (which is not a T-SQL statement). This tells SQL server to stop the current query but does not terminate the session or connection.